# AR tag tracked, but overlapping with Pointgrey camera

Tags: ros, pointgrey, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a blackfly GigE camera and I want to use it to track a tag. Now the problem is I can detect the tag, but the tag frame is overlap with the camera frame. Does any body have any idea? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243270/ar-tag-tracked,-but-overlapping-with-pointgrey-camera/) by [zf](https://answers.ros.org/users/22939/zf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using `output_frame` you should specify the frame that the output cartesian frame is relative to. Detail can be found on the package's [wiki doc](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) where you can also find the concrete example launch files.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0